# Edit distance between two strings

Tags: edit-distance

If X denotes the length of string s1 and Y denotes the length of the string s2, then the  edit distance between s1 and s2 is never more than 
`Min(X,Y)` or `Max(X,Y)`? 
Please explain.

Comment: The worst case is when they have nothing in common. If I gave you the 5-char string "AAAAA", and the 8-char string "BBBBBBBB", what's the edit distance between them? Why? Because this is a "worst case", if you extend that reasoning, you'll have an answer and a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the exact definition of edit distance:

Let, $s1=a$, $s2=bb$

The edit distance between $s1,s2$ is 3 if allowed *only* insertions and deletions; but it is 2 if allowed insertions, deletions and substitutions.

With substitutions, it is clear that the number of letters you need to change is at most the length of the longer string.